# Html Button Fires Two Postbacks in Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, vb.net, postback

I have an Html button that I have set `runat="server"`. When I click this button I sometimes get two executions of the button code but only when running in Chrome browser. I know I can expect this due to the button being in an update panel, but when I run in Chrome I can't determine the async postback because the values are always the same (even on the second execution):

```
IsPostBack = True
IsCallback = False
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).IsInAsyncPostBack = True
ScriptManager1.IsInAsyncPostBack = True
```

aspx page as follows:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>  
            <button id="btnHtml1" runat="server" class="toolStripButton"><img src="../Images/ManLate32.png" alt="[Man Late]"/><br />Html Button</button>
            <button id="btnHtml2" runat="server" class="toolStripButton"><img src="../Images/PayCategory32.png" alt="[Pay Category]"/><br />Html Button 2</button>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</div>
</form>
```

My Code Behind:

```
Public Class ChromeBug
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub btnHtml1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHtml1.ServerClick
        Globals.SubmitCount += 1
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Submit Count:{0} IsPostBack:{1} IsCallBack:{2} IsAsyncPostBack:{3} IsInAsyncPostBack2:{4}", Globals.SubmitCount, IsPostBack, IsCallback, ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).IsInAsyncPostBack, ScriptManager1.IsInAsyncPostBack.ToString))
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnHtml2_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHtml2.ServerClick
        Globals.SubmitCount += 1
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Submit Count:{0} IsPostBack:{1} IsCallBack:{2} IsAsyncPostBack:{3} IsInAsyncPostBack2:{4}", Globals.SubmitCount, IsPostBack, IsCallback, ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).IsInAsyncPostBack, ScriptManager1.IsInAsyncPostBack.ToString))
    End Sub
End Class
```

I tried adding the webkit javascript file but seemed to have no effect. I have also read in many places that this is due to empty src values but I don't have these.

Comment: have you tried to disable the button with javascript onclick?

Comment: @happygilmore - I don't understand how that would help?